# What are the odds of a digit appearing anywhere in a string of digits?

Tags: probability

Let's say you have a string of digits of any length and you want to know the odds whether ANY digit appears in that string? For example, the odds of the digit '4' appearing in '0123242234422'?

It seems to me the answer should be 1 in 10, since the probability of the second or subsequent digit in the string being '4' doesn't depend on whether or not the first is '4'. So regardless of the length, the odds remain the same as the odds of the letter '4' appearing in a string of length 1.

Does this seem right?

Comment: The odds of the digit '4' appearing in '0123242234422' are $100\%$.

Comment: You need to define the question better. I'm assuming you mean a random string using digits $0-9$?

Comment: Seriously?  Do you honestly think the probability that there is a person name Hugo lives at 2314 W. Amsterdam, Apt. #316 is the exact same probability that a person name Hugo lives in New York City?

Comment: One thing that you do have right is that the probability that the 7th digit of a 27 digit number is 1/10 and doesn't depend on the value of any of the other digits.  But we aren't asking what it the probability of the 7th digit.  Why are asking what is the probability of that either the 1st, the 2nd, the 3rd, or the 4th, th 5th....etc that any one or more than one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pick $n$ digits uniformly and independently, the chance that each one is not a $4$ is $\frac 9{10}$.  The chance that none of them is a $4$ is $(\frac 9{10})^n$, so the chance of at least one $4$ is $1-(\frac 9{10})^n$.  This goes to $1$ as $n$ gets large.

Comment: Thanks! My understanding was faulty then and this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

What is the probability that in an 1 bedroom apartment there will be a person named "Hugo"? "Hugo" is relatively rare name so less than 1 in 250 seems reasonable.

So what is the probability of a person in New York City is named Hugo?  Well, the probability that a person named Hugo living in the second or third appartment doesn't depend on the person in the first apartment so it's still less than 1 in 250.

Does that make sense?

The probability (not "odds") of a *specific* digit is always 1/10.  (Assuming normal randomness and predictability.)  That is true.  But if asking if the digit "4" appears *anywhere* in a 13 digit number is *not* the same thing as asking does a 4 occur in the 5-place of the 13 th digit.  Just like asking if Hugo occurs *anywhere* in New York City is not the same as asking does Hugo occur in *that* specific appartment on 15th floor of the North-east corner of Columbus and 134th.

The probabilty of of "4" occurring int the 1st digit is 1/10, in the second is 1/10, but in *either* the 1st **OR** the 2nd is 19/100.  In either the first or the second or the third is 271/1000.  And so on.

So how do we figure this.

Well, the probability of the first digit *not* being "4" is 9/10.  The probability of the first and second *both* not being "4" is $(9/10)(9/10)= (9/10)^2 = 81/100$.  The probability of *all* $n$ digits not being $4$ is $(9/10)^n$.

So the probability of at least one digit being "4" is $1$ minus the probability of the *all* NOT being "4".  i.e. $1 - (9/10)^2$.

So the probability of a 13 digit number having a "4" is $1 -.9^{13} = 0.7458134171671$.  This shouldn't be surprising.  There are a lot of digits so for *none* of them to be "4" ought to seem a bit unlikely.

Comment: Yes, thanks so much. This clarifies the problem and explains where I went wrong with my thinking. Surprisingly a few other people I discussed this with also assumed that the odds did not change depending on the length of the string so it seems like a common misunderstanding.